# Fetch data from 3 collections - Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

How to perform more than 2 join in `mongodb`. I know the concept `join` is only for `SQL` but still now I need the data from 2nd collection matching the id of the 1st collection and data from 3rd collection matching the id of the 2nd collection.I used `.populate` and I got the data from the 2nd collection. But how can I connect the 2nd and the 3rd collection ?

Comment: Some clear-cut examples here would help your cause.

Comment: three-collection joins are already problematic in MongoDB and should be avoided by denormalization. When you need to join even three collections, you seriously need to reconsider your schema.